# Model Not Updating Correct Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I update a row on my database setting table codeigniter. If I just update one item then it changes every row to that one that got updated. If I use INSERT INTO Its is OK but would rather use update.

It should only just update one that is been updated.

**Model**

```
<?php    
class Model_setting extends CI_Model {    
   public function editSetting($group, $data, $website_id = 0) {    
      //$this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . $this->db->dbprefix . "setting WHERE website_id  = '" . (int)$website_id . "' AND `group` = " . $this->db->escape($group) . " ");

      foreach ($data as $key => $value) {    
         if (!is_array($value)) {
            $this->db->query("UPDATE " . $this->db->dbprefix . "setting SET website_id = '" . (int)$website_id . "', 

            `group` = " . $this->db->escape($group) . ", 
            `key` = " . $this->db->escape($key) . ", 
            `value` = " . $this->db->escape($value) . "

            ");

         } else {

            $this->db->query("UPDATE " . $this->db->dbprefix . "setting SET 

            website_id = '" . (int)$website_id . "', 
            `group` = " . $this->db->escape($group) . ", 
            `key` = " . $this->db->escape($key) . ", 
            `value` = " . $this->db->escape(serialize($value)) . ", 
            serialized = '1'

            ");    
         }    
      }    
   }

   public function deleteSetting($group, $website_id = 0) {    
      $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . $this->db->dbprefix . "setting WHERE 
         website_id = '" . (int)$website_id . "' AND 
         `group` = " . $this->db->escape($group) . "
      ");    
   }

   public function editSettingValue($group = '', $key = '', $value = '', $website_id = 0) {
      if (!is_array($value)) {

         $this->db->query("UPDATE " . $this->db->dbprefix . "setting SET 

            `value` = ". $this->db->escape($value) ." WHERE 
            `group` = " . $this->db->escape($group) . " AND 
            `key` = ". $this->db->escape($key) ."
            AND website_id = '" . (int)$website_id . "'

         ");

      } else {

         $this->db->query("UPDATE " . $this->db->dbprefix . "setting SET 

            `value` = ". $this->db->escape(serialize($value)) .", 
            serialized = '1' WHERE 
            `group` = " . $this->db->escape($group) ."
            AND `key` = " . $this->db->escape($key) . "
            AND website_id = '" . (int)$website_id . "'

         ");    
      }
   }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use WHERE clause with UPDATE query to update selected rows otherwise all the rows would be affected.

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE " . $this->db->dbprefix . "setting SET website_id = '" . (int)$website_id . "', 

            `group` = " . $this->db->escape($group) . ", 
            `key` = " . $this->db->escape($key) . ", 
            `value` = " . $this->db->escape($value) . "
            WHERE `id`= $id ");
                    ^ replace with your condition
```

The same should be done for query in `else` part too.

Answer (score 0):

You've missed the **`WHERE`** clause in your query. Also use [Codeigniter's Active Record](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update) instead of raw SQL queries.

```
$data = array(
          'website_id' => $website_id,
          'group' => $group,
          'key' => $key,
          'value' => $value
       );

$this->db->where('id', $id);       // `id` is just for example
$this->db->update($this->db->dbprefix . 'setting', $data);
```

**Advantages of using Active Records:**

1) A major benefit to using the Active Record features is that it allows you to create database independent applications, since the query syntax is generated by each database adapter. 
2) It provides a more simplified interface.
3) It also allows for safer queries, since the values are escaped automatically by the system.

Comment: No luck `Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'

UPDATE `oc_setting` SET `website_id` = 0, `group` = 'config', `key` = NULL, `value` = NULL WHERE `id` IS NULL

Filename: C:\Xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\codeigniter-cms\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330`

Comment: That is just for example. `WHERE` clause identifies the row which you want to `UPDATE/DELETE`.

Comment: `UPDATE/DELETE` without a `WHERE` clause will make action on every row on that particular table. So replace `id` field  with the field you want to `UPDATE`

Comment: The reason why it is set up like that is so I do not have to tell what rows to update manually. because I have to many I do stuff like this on controller example `if (trim($this->input->post('config_maintenance'))) {
   $data['config_maintenance'] = $this->input->post('config_maintenance');
  } else {
   $data['config_maintenance'] = $this->configs->get('config_maintenance');
  }`